# VS Code Terminal ignoring CR

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

My VS Code terminal is currently ignoring CR in linux shells (WSL-fish, WSL-bash, git-bash):

[image]

This doesn't occur when using those terminals natively.  Any idea what might cause this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Although I wasn't using WSL in a remote fashion (just as a terminal) I tried installing the Remote-WSL extension when VS Code recommended it and that fixed the problem.